# Cannot build InAppSettingsKitSampleApp

Tags: xcode, inappsettingskit

I just downloaded and unpacked the ZIP for InAppSettingsKit.
For all three versions of the sample app, I am having problems when trying to build and run in Xcode 10.0:

- IASKSampleAppStaticLibrary.xcodeproj: fatal error: 'InAppSettingsKit/IASKSpecifier.h' file not found
- InAppSettingsKitSampleApp.xcodeproj: CustomViewCell.xib:global: error: Compiling IB documents for earlier than iOS 7 is no longer supported.
- InAppSettingsKitSampleAppStoryboard.xcodeproj: 'InAppSettingsKit/IASKAppSettingsViewController.h' file not found (in SettingsViewController.h)

Are these sample apps not up-to-date or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open the `InAppSettingsKit.xcworkspace` and select any target.

Comment: My bad, I did not open the workspace ... thanks a lot for the quick reply!!